# Getting logs from Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, intellij-idea, otroslogviewer

I work with Gradle project (IntelliJ, Gradle, Tomcat, Spring). I established a remote Tomcat Server - I managed how to deploy, debug and so on, but I can't connect from any tool to "listen" on changes in `catalina.out` file on Tomcat Server.

I would like to see logs in any window in any of programs on developer computer - is it possible to remotely observe changes on this file using different program than PuTTY and SSH connection?

I've seen tools like "otroslogviewer" but I didn't find any option to establish connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OtrosLogViewer](https://github.com/otros-systems/otroslogviewer) support virtual file systems. When you are opening file in path just type "sftp://host/" or "smb://host/share/